# Replaying messages on pubsub emulator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm new to pubsub emulator and I'm trying to explore the replay message feature. I don't know how to replay messages in the emulator. I tried looking for some solutions online but there isn't much content or research there. When I tried to create a snapshot for my subscription as mentioned in the gcp for actual subscriptions, it gave me an error saying resource (subscription) not found.

If anyone has any idea on how to replay messages on pubsub emulator, I'd really appreciate the guidance or any references.

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show exactly the commands or code you ran, including the startup of the emulator.